# PHP switch case statement. How to manage default values

Tags: php, html

This is my switch-case script:

```
switch ($_GET['page'])
{
case '?users':
.....
default: echo 'Welcome';

   }
```

This script work fine but when i load page first time he return error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: page in
```

I know why because script does't knows what value is. How to set default value and avoid error?

Comment: Before the switch case `$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : '';`

Comment: What Debflav means is that there's no element in the array `$_GET` for the key `page`, so you need to make sure that there's something, even an empty string.

Comment: **ALSO**:for `whatever.php?page=users` the value of `$_GET['page']` will be `users` NOT `?users`

Comment: Solve. Thanks switch (isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : '')
{

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia Thanks to be more specific. I'm lazy sometimes :D

Comment: @user3747585 : It's better to store the result of the ternary operator in a new variable before the switch case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `isset()`:**EDITED**

```
if(isset($_GET['page'])){
    switch ($_GET['page'])
    {
    case 'users':
    .....
    default: echo 'Welcome';

       }
}
```

Comment: -1 From the [isset() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php): `Returns TRUE if var exists and has value other than NULL, FALSE otherwise.` How can you `false == '?users'`?

Comment: @Francisco Presencia i was editing that why downvote.

Comment: Because your previous code was blatantly wrong (you shouldn't switch a true/false). Now I cancelled the downvote.

Comment: The case statement is still incorrect, unless the query string is `index.php?page=?users` - which would be illogical/strange if it was.

Answer (score 4):

**1a)** Check the index `page` exists

```
if( array_key_exists('page', $_GET) ) {

}
```

**1b)** Set a default value

```
$_GET['page'] = array_key_exists('page', $_GET) ? $_GET['page'] : '';
```

**2)** Your case statement is incorrect

```
case 'users' :
 //...
break;
```

**3)** All the code together

```
$_GET['page'] = array_key_exists('page', $_GET) ? $_GET['page'] : '';
  switch ($_GET['page']) {
      case 'users':
              //...
      break;
      default: 
              echo 'Welcome';
      break;
   }
```

#### Tips

- Make sure you `break;` the case block.
- Always check indexes are there before blindly using them

Comment: Does `default` also need the `break;`? That's news for me. Well, maybe I never put it since it's always the last *case* so it's okay.

Comment: [Not using `break;`](https://eval.in/184493). `default` doesn't need a break only if it's the last case - but doing the way I did it is mainly a habit and somewhat easier to read because each case is in uniform ( case -> new line (w/ indent) -> new line `break`). Idk... :P

Comment: I put the last `break` also . Indeed, I think he's optional. +1 for elaborate answer.

Comment: Thank you @Debflav :) (The last case doesn't need a break & default isn't always the last case - because of strange/illogical code writing)